# What is the meaning of 'physical gauge'?

Tags: terminology, gauge-theory, gauge

What does it mean for a gauge to be a physical gauge in your gauge choice of the theory, and why is it called the ["physical gauge"](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=physical+gauge)?

Comment: No gauge choice is more physical than any other. That's the fundamental *principle* of gauge theories, and I have never heard the term "physical gauge". Can you add to your question in which context you have seen this terminology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Physical gauge* presumably refers to [*unitary gauge*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarity_gauge), where Faddeev-Popov ghosts and other unphysical degrees of freedom  decouple from the theory.